# Make a monocolor jpeg file encoded one bit per pixel?

Tags: imagemagick, png, jpeg, tiff

For example, I see the following output. I don't quite understand its complete meaning. But when I look at the figure, it is just black and white, without gray or other color.

```
$ file 0447.jpg
0447.jpg: JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01, aspect ratio, density 1x1, segment length 16, baseline, precision 8, 1725x2751, components 1
```

The file size is 652708. To encode, 1725x2751 bits, the file size should be no more than `1725 * 2751/8 = 593184.4`. But the file size is bigger than this.

So it seems that a pixel is not encoded as one bit. Is there a way to shrink the size of the file (without loss of info) so that one pixel is one bit (maybe using other formats)?

Comment: Why have you tagged `ImageMagick` - there doesn't seem to be any IM involved? Have you considered a PNG, they tend to work very well for low bit-depth images.

Comment: In JPEG a channel is always 8-bit AFAIK, even if with only two values it should compress quite well.

Comment: ImageMagick can be used for conversion if the current format of jpeg is not appropriate.

Comment: @xenoid but the file size is bigger than what would be 1-bit per pixel. So the compression is not very good. What format allows 1-bit per pixel?

Comment: PNG, TIFF, GIF.  Please post your input image, your command line and your output image.  JPG is not compatible with 1-bit per pixel images.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use IM identify to find the actual bits-per pixel.  Use EXIFTOOL.

Input JPG:

[image]

Exiftool shows BitsPerSample of 8

```
exiftool -s -ee -g1 -u -n -D cow.jpg
---- ExifTool ----
    - ExifToolVersion                 : 12.44
---- System ----
    - FileName                        : cow.jpg
    - Directory                       : .
    - FileSize                        : 16214
    - FileModifyDate                  : 2022:10:14 11:31:44-07:00
    - FileAccessDate                  : 2022:10:14 11:31:44-07:00
    - FileInodeChangeDate             : 2022:10:14 11:31:44-07:00
    - FilePermissions                 : 100644
---- File ----
    - FileType                        : JPEG
    - FileTypeExtension               : JPG
    - MIMEType                        : image/jpeg
    - ImageWidth                      : 300
    - ImageHeight                     : 300
    - EncodingProcess                 : 0
    - BitsPerSample                   : 8 <-------
    - ColorComponents                 : 1
---- JFIF ----
    0 JFIFVersion                     : 1 1
    2 ResolutionUnit                  : 2
    3 XResolution                     : 28
    5 YResolution                     : 28
---- Composite ----
    - ImageSize                       : 300 300
    - Megapixels                      : 0.09
```

Threshold to GIF:

```
convert cow.jpg -threshold 50% cow_bw1.gif
```

Exiftool shows BitsPerPixel = 1

```
exiftool -s -ee -g1 -u -n -D cow_bw1.gif
---- ExifTool ----
    - ExifToolVersion                 : 12.44
---- System ----
    - FileName                        : cow_bw1.gif
    - Directory                       : .
    - FileSize                        : 2698
    - FileModifyDate                  : 2022:10:14 11:44:17-07:00
    - FileAccessDate                  : 2022:10:14 11:44:19-07:00
    - FileInodeChangeDate             : 2022:10:14 11:44:17-07:00
    - FilePermissions                 : 100644
---- File ----
    - FileType                        : GIF
    - FileTypeExtension               : GIF
    - MIMEType                        : image/gif
---- GIF ----
    - GIFVersion                      : 89a
    0 ImageWidth                      : 300
    2 ImageHeight                     : 300
  4.1 HasColorMap                     : 1
  4.2 ColorResolutionDepth            : 8
  4.3 BitsPerPixel                    : 1 <-------
    5 BackgroundColor                 : 1
---- Composite ----
    - ImageSize                       : 300 300
    - Megapixels                      : 0.09
```

Threshold to PNG:

```
convert cow.jpg -threshold 50% cow_bw1.png
```

Exiftool shows BitDepth of 1

```
exiftool -s -ee -g1 -u -n -D cow_bw1.png
---- ExifTool ----
    - ExifToolVersion                 : 12.44
    - Warning                         : [minor] Text/EXIF chunk(s) found after PNG IDAT (may be ignored by some readers)
---- System ----
    - FileName                        : cow_bw1.png
    - Directory                       : .
    - FileSize                        : 2251
    - FileModifyDate                  : 2022:10:14 11:49:20-07:00
    - FileAccessDate                  : 2022:10:14 11:49:21-07:00
    - FileInodeChangeDate             : 2022:10:14 11:49:20-07:00
    - FilePermissions                 : 100644
---- File ----
    - FileType                        : PNG
    - FileTypeExtension               : PNG
    - MIMEType                        : image/png
---- PNG ----
    0 ImageWidth                      : 300
    4 ImageHeight                     : 300
    8 BitDepth                        : 1 <-------
    9 ColorType                       : 0
   10 Compression                     : 0
   11 Filter                          : 0
   12 Interlace                       : 0
    - Gamma                           : 2.2
    - BackgroundColor                 : 1
    - ModifyDate                      : 2022:10:14 18:49:20
    - Datecreate                      : 2022-10-14T18:31:44+00:00
    - Datemodify                      : 2022-10-14T18:31:44+00:00
    - Datetimestamp                   : 2022-10-14T18:49:19+00:00
---- PNG-pHYs ----
    0 PixelsPerUnitX                  : 2800
    4 PixelsPerUnitY                  : 2800
    8 PixelUnits                      : 1
---- Composite ----
    - ImageSize                       : 300 300
    - Megapixels                      : 0.09
```

**ADDITION**

Here is how to make a 2-bit TIFF file.

```
convert lena.jpg -colorspace gray -depth 2 -type palette lena_d2.tif
```

```
exiftool -s -ee -g1 -u -n -D lena_d2.tif
---- ExifTool ----
    - ExifToolVersion                 : 12.44
---- System ----
    - FileName                        : lena_d2.tif
    - Directory                       : .
    - FileSize                        : 16642
    - FileModifyDate                  : 2022:10:14 16:42:42-07:00
    - FileAccessDate                  : 2022:10:14 16:42:43-07:00
    - FileInodeChangeDate             : 2022:10:14 16:42:42-07:00
    - FilePermissions                 : 100644
---- File ----
    - FileType                        : TIFF
    - FileTypeExtension               : TIF
    - MIMEType                        : image/tiff
    - ExifByteOrder                   : II
---- IFD0 ----
  256 ImageWidth                      : 256
  257 ImageHeight                     : 256
  258 BitsPerSample                   : 2 <------
  259 Compression                     : 1
  262 PhotometricInterpretation       : 3
  266 FillOrder                       : 1
  273 StripOffsets                    : 8
  274 Orientation                     : 1
  277 SamplesPerPixel                 : 1
  278 RowsPerStrip                    : 256
  279 StripByteCounts                 : 16384
  282 XResolution                     : 72
  283 YResolution                     : 72
  284 PlanarConfiguration             : 1
  296 ResolutionUnit                  : 2
  297 PageNumber                      : 0 1
  320 ColorMap                        : (Binary data 24 bytes, use -b option to extract)
---- Composite ----
    - ImageSize                       : 256 256
    - Megapixels                      : 0.065536
```

Comment: Is there a way to use 2bits, 4bits to represent a pixel? How to convert 8bit-pixel images to 2bit- or 4bit-pixel images?

Comment: -depth 2 or -depth 4 for image types that support it.

Comment: See my ADDITION in my answer.

Comment: I got a file with even larger size with just 2bits. Is there an option that I should use for compression?

Comment: JPG input is highly (lossy) compressed. TIFF supports LZW and ZIP (lossless) compression. Lossy compression can compress much smaller than lossless compression. Add -compress LZW.  But it likely will still be larger than your input JPG.